# How to use Azure Speech to Text transcription in batch - Python code

Tags: python, azure, text, blob, speech

I have a problem with the conection of my azure blob with Azure Speech to Text Api REST in Python. If someone hava an example code in Python I would be very grateful if any of you could lend me a hand.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my sample code for your needs.

1. Generate the blob url with SAS token for your audio file stored in Azure Blob Storage via Azure Storage SDK for Python which be installed by command `pip install azure-storage`.

   ```
   from azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice import BaseBlobService
   import numpy as np

   account_name = '<your account name>'
   account_key = '<your account key>'
   container_name = '<your container name>' # for example, `test`
   blob_name = '<your blob name>' # for example, `whatstheweatherlike.wav`

   blob_service = BaseBlobService(
       account_name=account_name,
       account_key=account_key
   )

   from azure.storage.blob import BlobPermissions
   from datetime import datetime, timedelta
   import requests

   sas_token = blob_service.generate_blob_shared_access_signature(container_name, blob_name, permission=BlobPermissions.READ, expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1))
   print(sas_token)
   url_with_sas = blob_service.make_blob_url(container_name, blob_name, sas_token=sas_token)
   print(url_with_sas)
   ```
2. Read the content of the blob url of your audio file, then to call Azure Speech-to-Text REST API, please refer to the offical document [Speech-to-text REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/rest-speech-to-text). At here, I used an offical audio sample named [whatstheweatherlike.wav](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/master/samples/csharp/sharedcontent/console/whatstheweatherlike.wav) which you can get from [samples/csharp/sharedcontent/console/whatstheweatherlike.wav](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/samples/csharp/sharedcontent/console/whatstheweatherlike.wav) of the GitHub Repo `Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk`.

   ```
   import requests

   subscription_key = '<your subscription key>'
   service_region = '<your service_region>' # for example, `eastasia`

   def get_token(subscription_key, service_region):
       fetch_token_url = f"https://{service_region}.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issuetoken"
       headers = {
           'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key
       }
       response = requests.post(fetch_token_url, headers=headers)
       access_token = str(response.text)
       return access_token

   access_token = get_token(subscription_key, service_region)
   #print(access_token)

   endpoint = f"https://{service_region}.stt.speech.microsoft.com/speech/recognition/conversation/cognitiveservices/v1?language=en-US"

   audio_blob_url_with_sas = url_with_sas # it's from STEP 1.
   r = requests.get(audio_blob_url_with_sas)

   headers = {
       'Accept': 'application/json;text/xml',
       'Content-Type': 'audio/wav; codecs=audio/pcm; samplerate=16000',
       'Authorization': f"Bearer {access_token}" # Or just use `'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key` instead of `'Authorization'`
   }

   res = requests.post(endpoint, headers = headers, data = r.content)
   print(res.text)
   ```

Finally, I got the result as below.

```
{"RecognitionStatus":"Success","DisplayText":"What's the weather like?","Offset":300000,"Duration":13600000}
```